# После переноса на другой сервер , получаю следующую ошибку и у меня нет файла new_hard.tpl

Tags: php, opencart

Сайт сделан на Opencart.
Выдает следующее сообщение об ошибке:

> Notice: Error: Could not load template/var/www/atech.tj/web/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/new_hard.tpl!in /var/www/clients/client202/web493/web/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modification_system_engine_loader.php on line 86.

Comment: А этот файл у вас действительно есть по указанному пути? И какие права на доступ к нему если он там есть?

Comment: нет , там такого файла не существует

Comment: а если добавить , то внутри него что должно быть?

Comment: В каком контексте вы вызываете этот файл? Особо не знаком с `Opencart`, но думаю, что там должен быть базовый шаблон для какой-то страницы или функционала.

Comment: если честно я сам не сделал сайт , нам разработали и после переноса такая ошибка выдается)

Comment: Скорее всего при переносе не все переменные изменили, просмотрите внимательно файл config.php

Comment: У Вас же пути разные. Видимо где-то жестко прописан путь до шаблона `/atech.tj/web/`, хотя по идее нужно вроде как `/clients/client202/web493/`

Comment: т.е. вот так
/var/www/clients/client202/web493/atech.tj/web/catalog/

Answer (score 0):

В базовой сборке `opencart` нет файла `new_hard.tpl`. Это модификация, следовательно подключается через кешированные копии исходных файлов. 
А кеши, видимо, `vqmod` не развернулись.

Сперва в админке, в модификаторах очистите кеш и обновите (две кнопки справа сверху).

Если не поможет, идёте в конень сайта, папка vqmod и в ней чистите кеши (vqcache). Также почистите кеши `ocmod` поп пути system/storage/modifications.

Comment: как это сделать если не заходит ни на сайт ни на админку

Comment: У вас должен быть доступ к сайту: админка, хостинг, фтп. Есть ли один любой из них?

Comment: к фтп есть доступ , я пробовал удалить внутренные файлы (vqcache) и удалил файлы system/storage/modifications

Comment: перегрузите сайт в браузере ctrl+f5 и кеш браузера почистите.

Comment: сделал , не получилось

Comment: может доступы отправлю , можете исправить?*

Comment: давайте гляну, не вопрос

Comment: вы сидите в телеграме или в вайбере ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63604/discussion-between-kirill-korushkin-and-akbar).